# How to list tags for the current post - Eleventy js?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks, eleventy

I am using Eleventy JS. And I can't list the tags for the current post. There is nothing written about this in the official documentation.

All tags are listed easily. But for the current post I can not display the tags on the screen

**This code to list all tags in Eleventy JS config file**

```
      // Display tag list on page
  eleventyConfig.addCollection('tagsList', function (collectionApi) {
    const tagsList = new Set()
    collectionApi.getAll().map((item) => {
      if (item.data.tags) {
        // handle pages that don't have tags
        item.data.tags.filter((tag) => !['posts'].includes(tag)).map((tag) => tagsList.add(tag))
      }
    })
    return tagsList
  })
```

**This loop of outputting tags in the template**

```
---
permalink:  /blog/category/

pagination:
  data: collections
  size: 77
---

<h1>Tags</h1>

<ul>
    {% for tag in collections.tagsList %}
        <a href="/blog/category/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**I use Nunjucks**

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [mcve]. Consider sharing the front-matter for the post, maybe the collection, and also the code you're using to list the tags. What template language are you using?

Comment: Good idea. I'll show you the code now

Comment: Also, please edit the question. Do not post code in the comments

Comment: I updated my question and added code examples. Look here please

Comment: May you add a `console.log` before the `return tagsList` line, build the project, and post what it shows in the question?

Comment: What data should be passed to console.log?

Comment: Try `tagsList`? Also use `forEach` if you do not need to return from `map`

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: What was it? Please may you share that by posting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Displaying tags for the current post with filter:

```
{% for tag in tags -%}
    {% if tag !== 'posts' %}
        <a class="tag" href="/blog/category/{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: Why was this the solution? --- Ah because you're using `tags` not `collection.tagsList`?

Comment: collection.tagsList doesn't work in my case and I don't know why. But looping over the "tags" array works great